# update a table in SSIS periodically

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-update, insert-update

How to do regular updates to a database table in SSIS. The table has foreign key constraints. 
I have a package running every week, and I have to update the data in the table from a flat file. Most of the contents are the same with update values and other new rows.

**UPDATE** : My data file contains updated contents ( some rows missing, some rows added, some modified ). The data file does not have the Primary keys ( I create the primary keys when I first bulk insert the data from the data file ), on subsequent SSIS package runs, I need to update the table with new data file contents.

e.g.

```
table
---------------------------------------------
1    Mango   $0.99
2    Apple   $0.59
3    Orange  $0.33


data file 
---------------------------------------------
Mango   0.79
Kiwi    0.45
Banana  0.54
```

How would I update the table with data from the file. The table has foreign key constraints with other tables.

Comment: Is the issue that you want to schedule it (use a SQL Agent Job) or that you want to Update as well as Insert data?

Comment: @ElectricLlama The issue is updating the table.

Comment: So as ElectricLlama said, create a SQL Agent Job and schedule running the SSIS package there. :)

Comment: @Kahn If only I knew magic !!! I can schedule it in SQL sever agent, that is not the problem. The problem is that I am not sure how to update the existing table with foreign key constraints and without changing the primary keys.

Comment: This is why people appreciate examples. :) Is your update touching FK-constraints? And if it's an update, how would primary keys be an issue? Basically, give us an example of what's in the table, what you're taking there, and why FK's and PK's become a problem?

Comment: @Kahn I have updated the question, I guess it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach, to load massive group data instead of dealing row by row:

On database

- create an staging table (e.g. StagingTable [name], [price])
- Create a procedure (you may need to change the objects names, and add
  transaction control and error handling etc just a draft):

  ```
  create procedure spLoadData
  ```

  as
  begin

  ```
  update DestinationTable
     set DestinationTable.Price = StagingTable.Price
    from DestinationTable
    join StagingTable
      on DestinationTable.Name = StagingTable.Name

  insert into DestinationTable
        (Name, Price)
  select Name, Price
    from StagingTable
   where not exists (select 1 
                       from DestinationTable
                      where DestinationTable.name = StagingTable.Name)
  ```

  end

On SSIS

- Execute SQL Task with (truncate [staging_table_name])
- Data Flow task transferring from your Flat File to the Staging Table
- Execute SQL Task calling the procedure you created (spLoadData).

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate it. Actually I have 2 million records and this looks right.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the few thoughts/steps:

- Create a Flat File Connection manger.
- Take Data flow task.
- Create Flat File Source with connection manager just created.
- Take lookup transformation(s) as many as you need to get FK values based on your source file values.
- Take a lookup transformation after all above lookups, to get all values from Destination table.
- Keep Conditional split and compare source values and destination values.
- If all columns matched then UPDATE, else INSERT.
- Map above conditional split results accordingly to OLEDB Destnation/OLEDB Command.

Give a try and let me know the results/comments.